# Llamar a numero al hacer click en un <p>

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos

tengo una duda, y es como hacer para que al hacer click sobre un número de teléfono, haga un href="tel:######"

Pero necesito que llame al número que traigo con php de la base de datos

```html
<p><?php echo $row['telefono']; ?></p>
```

He probado algo asi...pero ya se que no funcionará:

```html
<p href="tel:<?php $row['telefono']; ?>"><?php echo $row['telefono']; ?></p>
```

Comment: El atributo href es para las etiquetas a y no p, prueba a cambiar tu etiqueta, además te falta el echo al asignar el valor a href

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto debería funcionar, aunque no lo he podido probar porque no tengo un teléfono ahora mismo:

```html
<p data-tel="tel:<?php echo $row['telefono']; ?>"><?php echo $row['telefono-friendly']; ?></p>
```

Es decir, muestras el teléfono en un formato amigable y colocas el teléfono al qué llamar en un atributo de tipo data llamado tel.

Luego en jQuery por ejemplo:

```
            $("p").click(function() {
                window.open($(this).data("tel"));
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo el uso de **JavaScript** para realizar la operación que deseas.
Se añade una acción **onclick** en el elemento deseado y así puedes dar uso al elemento cuando le des click.

> **NOTA: Si el elemento es "<a>" que posee una acción en el click se deberá añadir "preventDefault" si no quieres que se realice**

te añado un ejemplo de javaScript puro y otro con jquery:

**JS puro**

```js
function llamarFunction(e){
    window.location.assign(e.getAttribute("href"));
}
```

```html
<p id="callButton" href="tel:666000000" onclick="llamarFunction(this)">666000000</p>
```

**JQuery**

```js
$("#callButton").click(function(e) {
    window.location.assign($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="callButton" href="tel:666000000">666000000</p>
```

> **Te he puesto datos hardcodeados para el ejemplo**

Answer (score 0):

---

Muchas gracias por vuestras aportaciones, he ido probando y la solución más sencilla y que me funciona os la dejo por aquí por si alguien más tiene esta duda.

```html
<a href="tel:<?php echo $row['telefono']; ?>"></a>
```